# Me salta el error de que excedi el limite de re-renders en React cuando uso el componente modal de materialUI

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

he estado trabajando en un proyecto basico de una app de lista de tareas donde quiero mostrar cada lista dentro de una ventana Modal, componente que vi entre los que incluye la biblioteca de materialUI base pero al intentar usarla me salta el error de la pregunta, hasta ahora el codigo que he escrito es simple, para el modal seria

```
<Modal
    open={ openNote }
    onClose={ setOpenNote(false) }
>
    <h1>Hola</h1>
</Modal>
```

para llamar a la funcion que hace aparecer al modal puse un evento onClick en un Box que es un componente de la misma biblioteca, este lo renderice aplicando la funcion .map a un array asi

```
{showNotes.map((note) => <Box sx={{ 
        borderRadius:'10px',
        borderColor:'white',
        borderStyle:'solid',
        width:'10rem',
        textAlign:'center'
        }}
        padding={1}
        margin={1}
        onClick={ () => { setOpenNote(true) } }
    >
        {note}
    </Box>)}
```

finalmente el useState que controla cuando se abre el modal lo inicialize el false. muchas gracias de antemano a cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se presenta en la propiedad `onClose` del `Modal`. Estás ejecutando directamente la función `setOpenNote(false)` como propiedad. Eso genera que React ejecute esa función apenas el componente se monta, lo cuál genera un re-render, lo cuál genera que React ejecute la función y así infinitamente.

Debería ser `onClose={() => setOpenNote(false)}`. Es decir, pasarle una función anónima al `onClose` del `Modal` y no la ejecución de la función directamente.